# Multiple AJAX Requests for sets of form elements

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I'm a pretty novice programmer who is trying to make a heartbeat script that grabs an id from the current page and sends it to heartbeat.php where the following happens:

1) I look up in the **schedule** table the **currentlocation** field that corresponds with the id I just sent over.

2) I then encode the value I found in the **currentlocation** field in JSON

Here's the code for heartbeat.php:

```
<?php
/*** mysql hostname ***/
$hostname = 'localhost';

/*** mysql username ***/
$username = '********';

/*** mysql password ***/
$password = '*********';

$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=sv", $username, $password);
$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT currentlocation FROM schedule WHERE apptid = :apptid");
$statement->execute(array(':apptid' => $apptid));
$row = $statement->fetch();
echo json_encode($row['currentlocation']);

?>
```

On the html side, I am using php for a while loop pulling patient info from the database, so the ID-NUMBER-1 and ID-NUMBER-2 would be the corresponding id's in the database.

Here's the html:

```
<!--  FIRST SET: the id is ID-NUMBER-1  -->

<div class='jcontainer'>
      <div style='display:none; class='jcontainerid'>ID-NUMBER-1</div>
      <button class='checkIn' data-param='button_ID-NUMBER-1'>Check In</button>
      <form method='post' class='myForm' action=''>
           <select name='locationSelect' class='locationSelect' data-param='location_ID-NUMBER-1'>
                <option value='1'>Exam Room</option>
                <option value='2'>Exam Room 2</option>
                <option value='3'>X-Ray Room</option>
                <option value='1000'>Check Out</option>
           </select>
      </form>
      <div class='finished' style='color:#ff0000;'>Checked Out</div>
</div>

<!--  SECOND SET: the id is ID-NUMBER-2  -->

<div class='jcontainer'>
      <div style='display:none; class='jcontainerid'>ID-NUMBER-2</div>
      <button class='checkIn' data-param='button_ID-NUMBER-2'>Check In</button>
      <form method='post' class='myForm' action=''>
           <select name='locationSelect' class='locationSelect' data-param='location_ID-NUMBER-2'>
                <option value='1'>Exam Room</option>
                <option value='2'>Exam Room 2</option>
                <option value='3'>X-Ray Room</option>
                <option value='1000'>Check Out</option>
           </select>
      </form>
      <div class='finished' style='color:#ff0000;'>Checked Out</div>
</div>
```

So, the problem is, how can I do the following in JQuery:

1) For each jcontainer (or each set of form elements that I marked in my html), grab the id which is the text inside the div with the class of jcontainerid

2) then using a jquery heartbeat, for every 5 seconds the id of each jcontainer sent to the php page and the value of **currentlocation** sent back in JSON format.

Super thanks for any and all help. If you need any more details cleared up, please just ask and I'll be happy to help!

Comment: You need to see the Ajax and traversing section of jquery documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use .each() to iterate over each jcontainer, see more here:

http://api.jquery.com/each/

Here is an axample of what you can do:

```
function dataToHeartbeat(){
  $(".jcontainer").each(function(){
    // grab the id
    var apptid = $(this + " > .jcontainerid").text();
    // Submit to heartbeat.php with JSON expected in return
    $.getJSON('heartbeat.php?apptid='+apptid, function(data){
      // Do something with resulting data
    });
  });
}
```

You can then use setTimeout() to call the function. Depending on your needs you can add setTimeout within the function to cause a continuous loop.